# View identity matrix

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-view

What does it mean for a View (android) to have an identity Matrix? For instance

```
final boolean hasIdentityMatrix() {
    return mRenderNode.hasIdentityMatrix();
}//in the View class
```

Comment: it means that no setScaleX|Y, setRotation[X|Y] or setTranslationX|Y|Z have been called

Comment: So it's the original view? I see. Thanks.